# How to let IIS not to refuse SignIn?ReturnUrl=%2F?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, iis

Well, I have finished my project in **ASP.NET MVC5** and I am trying to install my web app into local server **IIS**. I have used ASP Identity to manage the login but when installed in IIS chrome says `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I have done some basic configuration and permissions in the IIS server and I disabled the login return link and web app worked as expected in the IIS but I need the app with a login for security reasons. This is my configuration:

Authentication:

[image]

Folder Permissions:

[image]

Web.config

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
    <!--<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>-->
  </appSettings>



  <system.web>

    <!--<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>-->

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/InternalError.cshtml" />
  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>


  <!--ORIGINAL-->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Context"
         connectionString="Server=servername\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testingroles;Trusted_Connection=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="HotelRestTikalShared.Data.Context, HotelRestTikalShared">
        <databaseInitializer type="HotelRestTikalShared.Data.DatabaseInitializer, HotelRestTikalShared" />
      </context>
    </contexts>

    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>



</configuration>
```

I tried to upload this to ***Microsoft Azure*** with *Publish* button and web app worked there as expected but I do not know why it is not working in my local IIS. Anyone had this issue? Am I missing some other configuration? I cant find solution in the internet.
You can see a test of this webapp in azure https://testinghotel.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Azure App Service usually configures a valid binding and its corresponding networking/firewall for you automatically, but for your own local IIS server, you are responsible, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: Do you think this is firewall related issues? or I have to configure more stuff inside IIS?

Comment: try to check the logs if there is anything useful information available or not. also check your entered URL and iis bindings detail is correct or not. also refer this link for [Asp.Net MVC 5, how to impersonate a user on IIS](https://forums.asp.net/t/1961337.aspx?Asp+Net+MVC+5+how+to+impersonate+user+on+IIS)

Comment: I changed port and used https instead of http and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had same issue before. You cannot run a redirect link on a `Http` request using port 80. Change port number and set to `Https`.

Go to Actions> Bindings...

[image]

Click ***Add*** and change type to https and set any port you want to use and set SSL certificate to ***IIS Express Development Certificate***.

[image]

Now try to run web app using that new port.